# Javascript Canvas takes too much CPU

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Heyo, before asking a question I have to admit that javascript hasnt been to kind to me and would ask to not throw too many rocks at me for this question.

So I am writing a canvas based player with live video but the page where canvas is being executed consumes and insane amount of CPU power.

This is the routine that draws on the given canvas(player is the canvas that was passed)

```
var requestFrames = function(player) {

    console.log('Requesting frames for videoId ' + requestStream.videoId);

    //var imageElement = player;

    var ctx = player.getContext("2d");

    var displayImage = function(frame) {

        if (frame && frame.imageURL) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = frame.imageURL;
            img.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0)

        };
        }
        sendFrameRequest(requestStream.videoId, displayImage);
    };

    sendFrameRequest(requestStream.videoId, displayImage);
};
```

Please send help, thanks

**EDIT** : sendFrameRequest is a function that requests latest image from the server. I am working with a server that sends out live images from cameras(Its a video management system)

Comment: how and when are you calling the requestFrames and sendFrameRequest methods?

Comment: Its being summoned on click event

Comment: I know `requestAnimationFrame`, what is "sendFrameRequest"? Additionally, creating an image from an image url is indeed cpu intensive

Comment: sendFrameRequest is a function that requests latest image from the server

Comment: So then don't wonder why your cpu gets blown up... You are not streaming a video, you are transferring a whole bunch of full images one after another and displaying them. Your problem is not bad code but bad application design. You should switch to streaming videos instead of full frames.

Comment: Ah I see, I agree that streaming video would make it so much easier, its just our client has asked to use VMS that streams images this way instead of exposing a stream.

Comment: Then you need to decrease the frequency. Try `setTimeout` with a couple of milliseconds. However, requesting one frame after another each via an own http request will cause _a lot_ of overhead bandwidth. Maybe your server can do the streaming for you requesting the frames on the local system (it will still produce some load on the server, but using the local tcp stack instead of using the network will relax some performance matters)